# What does this javascript code snippet mean?

Tags: javascript

Here is the code snippet:

```
var prjId = navObj.itemId || navObj
```

Does this mean that prjId is either equal to navObj.itemId or navObj? What does it then mean that a variable is equal to navigation object?

Thank you in advance for answers!

Answer (score 3):

If `navObj.itemId` is set to `false` or has not been defined at all,

`prjId = navObj;`

otherwise:

`prjId = navObj.itemId;`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g has the more correct answer. If navObj.itemId was set to false, it would be defined and yet would set prjId to navObj.

Comment: @Jage correct. Didn't think about that. Updated answer to cover that corner.

Answer (score 3):

This is equivalent to the following:

```
var prjId;
if(navObj.itemId)
    prjId = navObj.itemId;
else
    prjId = navObj;
```

Answer (score 2):

No. The `||` operator first tries to convert `navObj.itemId` to a Boolean value.

- It will be converted to `true` if it is already the Boolean value, `true`, a number other than `0` or `NaN`, a non-empty string, or an object that is not `null` or `undefined`. These are known as "*truthy*" values.
- It will be converted to `false` if it is already the Boolean value `false`, `0`, `NaN`, an empty string, `null` or `undefined`. These are known as "*falsey*" values.

If `navObj.itemId` is "*truthy*", `navObj.itemId` is assigned to `prjId`, otherwise `navObj` is assigned to `prjId`.

**Further Reading**

- [Logical Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators)

Comment: I'm not js expert but that's not a ternary operator. To me it would mean that prjId is true if one of those condition is true. isn't it?

Comment: No, as I understand it, p.s.w.g's answer is not even discussing a ternary, but the /quality/ ("truthy" vs. "falsey") if you will of the items on either side of the `||` operator. If the /quality/ of the left side is truthy, then the variable is set to the /value/ of the left side. If not, the right side is used.

Comment: @user711061 Not exactly. The `||` operator in JS is a kind of simplified version of the `?:` operator. `x || y` is equivalent to `x ? x : y`. The result is `x` or `y`, not the truth values associated with them.

Answer (score 1):

It simply means that if the left operand of the logical or operator (||) is a truthy value then return it otherwise return the right operand.

The following values are always falsy:

- false
- 0
- empty string
- null
- undefined
- NAN (not a number)

So if `navObj.itemId` doesn't evaluate to anything of the above, then it will be assigned to the `prjId` variable.

This is widely used when we have optional parameters in a function, for example. It is a way of specifying the default value for an optional parameter. But of course that's not the only use of it.

Answer (score 0):

It sets prjId to the property of itemId on navObj, if it exists (evaluates to 'truthy'), if it doesn't exist (or it evaluates to 'falsy'), prjId gets set to navObj.